# ¿Es posible verificar si se conectaron a un puerto udp?

Tags: c#

Utilizo 'UdpClient' en un loop para escuchar determinado puerto udp, hay manera de verificar que el cliente se conectó a ese puerto, sin que este me haya enviado información?

Edición de comentario

```
    _addressInfo = addressInfo;
    _port = _addressInfo.PortIn;
    _ipIn = _addressInfo.IPAddressIn;
    var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_ipIn), _port);
    _running = true;

    using (_udpClient = new UdpClient(_port))
    {
        while (_running)
        {
          try
          {
             byte[] receivedDataByte = _udpClient.Receive(ref  ipEndPoint);
             if(receivedDataByte == null)
             {
                 Thread.Sleep(200);
                 continue;
             }

             GetInfo(receivedDataByte);

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              throw ex;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cual es tu codigo?

Comment: tenes que editar tu pregunta y colocar el codigo en la misma, y si te fijas no pasaste el codigo completo porque no estan las llaves que cierran el using, try, falta el catch. etc

Answer (score 0):

En UDP no existe el concepto de conexión tal como se usa en TCP. Cuando un programa abre un puerto UDP puede recibir paquetes desde cualquier ip sin distinción. La única forma de saber si un "cliente" puede enviar datos al "servidor" es que envié un dato y éste pueda ser leído.

Según Wikipedia:

> Permite el envío de datagramas a través de la red sin que se haya establecido previamente una conexión, ya que el propio datagrama incorpora suficiente información de direccionamiento en su cabecera. Tampoco tiene confirmación ni control de flujo, por lo que los paquetes pueden adelantarse unos a otros; y tampoco se sabe si ha llegado correctamente, ya que no hay confirmación de entrega o recepción

[Protocolo UDP en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_datagramas_de_usuario)